# Limit of the reciprocal without proving its existence

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=\infty$. Also, $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=g(x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}g(x)=f(x)$. If I apply L'Hospital's rule: $$L=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{L}$$ Is this sufficient to say that $L=1$ or do I have to prove that both limits exist?

Comment: Well the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = g(x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}g(x)=f(x)$ is a very strong condition. I believe that means that the function must be an exponential (some version of $e^x$).

Comment: Is $c$ a finite real?

Comment: Solving $f'' = g' = f$ gives $f = c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{-x}$, whose limit is finite as $x\to c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will indeed have to prove that the limit exists, L'Hôpital's rule rule only says that $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$, iff the second limit exists.

Answer (score 1):

If $f'=g$ and $g'=f$, then $f''=f$ so 
$$f(x) = Ae^x + Be^{-x}$$
For constants $A,B$ are the only functions verifying your hypothesis. So you're actually looking at the limit

$$\lim_{x\to c} \frac{Ae^x + Be^{-x}}{Ae^x - Be^{-x}}$$

If $c$ is finite, the value is 1 only if $B=0$.